# upgrading to .net 4.0 membership issues - GetUser error

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the problem seen before where `GetUser` has moved from `system.web.security` to `system.web.applicationstring`s.

I have made all the changes I can find but I am still having the problem

> "Specified Method is Not supported"

when I call `GetUser("username")`

My config file is as follows

```
<membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="conname" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
      <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri=""/>
  </providers>
</membership>
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <remove name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="conname"/>
    <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>

</system.web>
```

`<system.web> <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit = "true" targetFramework="4.0"> <assemblies> <remove assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" /> <add assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" /> </assemblies> </compilation>`

Any additional suggestions gratefully received

Comment: <system.web>
  <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit = "true"  targetFramework="4.0">
   <assemblies>
    <remove assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
   </assemblies>
  </compilation>